# How to delete data in laravel

Tags: laravel

How to data delete in laravel

MY link

```
 <a href="destroy/<?php echo $values->sln; ?>" >Delete</a>`
```

Route

```
Route::get('/destroy/{$id}','CrudCtl@destroy');
```

My Controller

```
public function destroy($id)
{
       DB::table('info')->where('sln',$id)->delete();

       return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eloquent you can delete model by

```
   $info = Info::findOrFail($id);
    $info->delete();
```

And can delete an existing Model By Key

```
App\Info::destroy($id);
```

And if you want to delete models By query
use this

```
App\Info::where('id', 0)->delete();
```